# How can I deal with a shadow that is distracting from text?

Tags: shadows

In my scene, I was rendering each area with light to make sure it looked good but came across a problem where the shadow from a picture was positioned in the middle of some text in the render. It seems very distracting and I want to avoid changing the camera's position.
The power of the light is 1000 W, the radius is 0, the blend is 0.911, and the max bounces is 1024. I am rendering it in cycles.
[image: The shadow][image: The setup in the viewport]

Comment: You could cheat by adding a little emission to the text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can lighten or completely eliminate the shadow by mixing a *Transparent BSDF* on shadow ray for that object's material.  Just change the *Transparent BSDF* from black to white to see the difference.

[image]